How do I prevent an extended frame when suspending and resuming an ffmpeg process?
I have a c# application where I have control of an ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org/) process. I am using it to capture video and audio, either from desktop or webcam. I am using code similar to the answer from this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206312/how-to-pause-resume-ffmpeg-video-capture-in-windows-from-c-sharp-application) to suspend and resume the process. However, while suspended, the captured video extends the frame it was suspended on for the entire duration of the suspension.
My arguments passed into the process:

-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt rgb24 output.mp4

I have tried adding -vf setpts=N/FR/TB to my arguments, and this works partially. It successfully prevents the extended frame, but then seriously affects the playback speed of the video.
How do I prevent this extended frame from occurring, or prevent the additional argument from affecting the playback speed of the video?
My ideal outcome is to have the process record, be suspended then resumed, and have the video play normally without having captured anything while suspended.
Record for 10 seconds, suspend for 20 seconds, record for 30 seconds, end recording -> should result in a 40 second video that plays back at normal speed.
I would love for a c# solution, but I believe the solution may be specific to the arguments I am passing in.

This is rather nasty. What does the resulting video "look like" at the frame level - is it one frame which has a very long timestamp? Can you do timestamp correction post-processing? Could you just kill and restart the capture instead?

@pjc50 As far as I can tell, it is one frame with a very long timestamp. I don't know a ton about the video side of things. Visually, if you play the video, it'll play normally, then for the 20 or so seconds the process is suspended, it shows the same frame for the duration. Due to the requirements of the software I'm working with, I can't kill and restart the process.

Alternate solution: use the Windows APIs for capture https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video - more work but more control. Why is kill and restart not an option?

@pjc50 I can't kill and restart because every process needs to be continuously running, sometimes upwards of a couple hours. Specifically there are some timing constraints that make completely stopping the process not feasible. And as much as I would like to use something other than ffmpeg, ffmpeg is passed down from above as what we are using.

gdigrab uses the system clock to assign timestamps. So, if you pause/resume, you will get a gap. Record in different instances and then use concat demuxer to join the segments.

Then I think you have no choice but to work out how to fix the timestamps. "-vf setpts=N/FR/TB" looks like it ought to work; does it work any better as a post-processing step (-v copy -a copy) on the video?

@pjc50 "-vf setpts=N/FR/TB" works partially. It does correctly move the frames from after the pause to where the pause starts, essentially skipping the paused time, but it also affects the framerate. A video that should be twenty seconds (10 seconds recording, 10 seconds paused, 10 seconds recording), is instead roughly ~10 seconds and plays back at an increased speed.
I'm still fairly new with ffmpeg, can I add -v copy -a copy in the same command?

@Gyan unfortunately I need to use the same instance to record the entire time. There are timing requirements with the rest of the software that don't allow the small delay in the startup of a new process.

What I was suggesting was to record a "bad" video to disk and then play with ffmpeg "copy" command lines, e.g. "-i bad_output.mp4  -v copy -a copy vf setpts=N/FR/TB test_output.mp4". Is the frame rate actually 30fps or has the wrong one been substituted under you?

"ffmpeg is passed down from above as what we are using" whoever told you you had to use ffmpeg is also responsible for telling you how to drive it. Given that it's one of the most complex tools out there.

@pjc50 inputting that command as is tells me I have an invalid loglevel "copy". I tried "-c:v copy" instead of -v copy, which informs me that filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.  I honestly have no idea what I'm doing here, and ideally I would have someone in the company that knows more about this than I do to ask questions, it's unfortunately not the case.

@this_is_a_display_name then you can do a post-process step where you split the input at the timestamp jumps into separate files and then concat them together.
